# Is it possible to fill_in a number field wo/ labels with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have a number field, that takes a `:product_quantity` with a button after it saying `"Add to Cart"`. My test works without adjusting the `number_field` but when I uncomment this line:

`product_from_shop.fill_in 'quantity', with: 5`

Stuff blows up. `Capybara::ElementNotFound`

It's about this line in my view:

`<%= f.number_field :product_quantity, value: booking.product_quantity, min: 1, max: 999, title: 'quantity' %>`

I tried several approaches, also searching for the class or id. Non work. There is no label, that would clutter my view.

`title` worked fine in other cases, without a form.

Also: I am using capybara webkit, because it uses JS.

Comment: What is 'product_from_shop', what is the actual HTML of the element, and what is the full error message you get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fill_in` uses the :fillable_field selector which will find any visible input or textarea area element except of type submit, image, radio, checkbox, or file.  It will find those elements id, name or placeholder attributes or by the text in an associated label element.  Since you don't have an associated label you're down to id, name or placeholder attribute.  Assuming `product_from_shop` is a wrapper element on the page you're using to scope this `fill_in` then

```
product_from_shop.fill_in '<something>_product_quantity', with: 5
```

should find and fill_in the element by id -  will depend on what model type the form is for (just look at the actual HTML to see what id was assigned).

If the product quantity field is the only fillable field inside product_from_shop you could also do

```
product_from_shop.fill_in with: 5 # same as product_from_shop.fill_in nil, with: 5
```

If none of those will work for you, you can move to using something like

```
product_from_shop.find(<more complicated query>).set '5'
```

To clarify your comment about `title` working previously - The `title` attribute is only matched when finding links and buttons.

Comment: Right on! I went with the middle one. I noticed I actually could use an id, but that would be odd, considering the page is showing multiple products. If I would need to differentiate in some later stage I could always wrap this one in some div. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `form_for` in Rails for this, then it should be generating an id that you can use. I am not familiar with the `product_from_shop.fill_in` form, I typically use `page`, but try one of these:

```
page.fill_in :product_from_shop_product_quantity, with: 5
```

or

```
page.fill_in "product_from_shop_product_quantity", with: 5
```